# About colour values in NV12 format

Tags: gstreamer

I need to change the pixel values in NV12 format videoframes including colours. as NV12 fomat has y component for brightness  and uv is interleaved with 2bytes. here i want to know the exact values to be kept in that y,u,v for required colours like red,green,blue.

....// Set Y, U, and V values                                                       y_pixel[0] =???; // Y component
uv_pixel[0] =???; // U component (or the first byte of UV)                                                        uv_pixel[1] =???; // V component (or the second byte of UV)
here nv12 has 2 planes i accessed them with stride concept and trying to modify pixel values .
i am expecting here to which values to be kept in above statements for getting required colours
is there any color table for NV12 format??